# PyQt4:Unable to open 2 gui windows at a time

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from test_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class StartQt4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui2=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui2.setupUi(self)      # ui2 setup
        self.ui.setupUi(self)       # ui  setup .interchanging these 2 lines gives 2 guis


        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.button_open,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.file_open)

    def file_open(self):
        self.ui.editor_window.setText('Yes u are doing good')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=StartQt4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Trying to create simple pyqt4 gui.My goal is to open two gui windows at a time and hence created 2 objects `ui` `ui2`.By swapping the lines that are commented,it works just fine,2 windows get opened.But when i leave it like this, only the `ui` object window get opened.How is that possible.They are just methods which are called at different times before displaying(`myapp.show()`) right? Just started learning pyqt4.

Comment: Those methods (`.setupUi()`) are being passed the `self` argument, which means that they are probably modifying your `StartQT4` class instance. You need to create multiple windows in different classes and show them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated class `Ui_MainWindow` doesn't represent the window itself, only the widgets contained in it. The window is the `self` parameter that you pass to `setupUi()`.

To have 2 windows, you need to create 2 `StartQt4` objects, each with only 1 `Ui_MainWindow`, and call `show()` for each of them.

Comment: I made a mess out of the question.Somehow I forgot to close the previously opened window and thought 2 windows were opened if I interchanged those two commented lines. And thnx for the awesome answer.It all make sense now.